# Can your vision see?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I come from the dark,
but I was born in the bright

I open your eyes into my origins

The cloths I give to everything and everyone, are simple to me

When I pass through you,
you can't see me,
because I'm as fast as your ***vision***.

But when I crash into something
, you observe.

Comment: Tip: The title may help you on something.

Comment: As one who loves physics and who also wrote a [similarly-written riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67883/i-am-described-by-temperature-and-never-by-looks-i-might-be-found-in-your-came), I assert with full confidence that the answer is Rot13(yvtug). If it is not, then I will make sure to share my upvote. DVL11 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be

> Light?

I come from the dark, but I was born in the bright

> The light comes out of the dark and its source is bright, of course

I open your eyes into my origins

> The light you see was generated long time ago!

The cloths I give to everything and everyone, are simple to me

> Colours!

When I pass through you, you can't see me, because I'm as fast as your vision.

> Light is as fast as light!

But when I crash into something , you observe.

> You can only see things that were "touched" by light.

Comment: Pretty much it!!
Vision was also a reference to "see" (it's what your eyes do) that is pronouced as "c" that is the constant of "speed of light" :)